# Keeping secondary workbook visible while interacting with original workbook userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which opens a secondary workbook (using a hyperlink to that workbook which is written in a cell in my original workbook). Then, a userform opens (a listbox which is populated with values from a row in the secondary workbook) along with the secondary workbook.

The problem:
Every time you click on the userform (even just to move it), the original workbook appears on top of the secondary workbook so that it's no longer visible.
For the purpose of the macro, I need the secondary workbook and the userform to stay visible at all times until the button at the bottom is clicked.

I tried many combinations of `.Activate`, `.Show`, `.xlMinimize`, `.xlMaximize`, `.Visible`, turn off screen updating, etc.
I think the problem is that the userform is an object of the original workbook so clicking it will always bring the original workbook to the front.

From one module:

```vb
Private Sub findColumns_button_Click()  'finds selected shelf options, starts building table in data sheet
    uf_TestSelector.Hide
        
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Set selected_index = New Collection
    Set hyperlinks = New Collection
        
    For i = 0 To descriptions.count - 1
        If ts_listBox.Selected(i) = True Then
            selected_index.Add i
                
            Dim hyplnk As Variant
            hyplnk = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Results").Cells(i + 3, 7).Value
            hyperlinks.Add hyplnk
        End If
    Next i
        
    ...
        
    Dim k As Integer
    For k = 1 To selected_index.count   'cycles through selected options, sets 'hyperlink to be opened, shows next userform
        ...
        hyperlink_A = hyperlinks(k)
        uf_ColSelectA.Show vbModeless  'shows the userform that needs to be 'interacted with
    Next k  
    ...
End Sub
```

From uf_ColSelectA:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim copyBook As Workbook
    Set copyBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=hyperlink_A)   'copyBook = secondary workbook
        
    Call findListBoxValues(shelves, copyBook)
    linkA_Lbox.MultiSelect = 1
    linkA_Lbox.List = shelves()
        
    copyBook.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and try to build one from your code so the issue is reproducible. That would it make much easier to help you. From your current description it is hard to tell what actually happens there. That would be more guessing than really helping.

Comment: I suspect that your form is not set as modeless. If the form is not set as modeless, clicking on the form will always bring the workbook where the form originated from. Try setting your form as modeless

Comment: as mentioned above in the `Userform_Show` command add `vbModeless`, so it would look like this `Userform_Show vbModeless`

Comment: @ZackE didn't work. Interacting with the userform still brings the original workbook to the front.

Comment: Try setting the `ShowNodal` property of the form to `False`

Comment: @Zac isn't that the same as doing uf_ColSelectA.Show vbModeless

Comment: Almost. If you set the property of the form as modeless, form is opened as modeless. If you do it through VBA, it tends to be a bit **flaky** as form is already created at that point. All `show` does is render the form visible

Comment: @Zac tried it: didn't work

Comment: Hmm, how bizarre, I just tried that and it works for me

Comment: @Zac I don't know what to tell ya. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Did you try moving `uf_ColSelectA.Show vbModeless` outside of the loop?  Im wondering if having the call for the UserForm in the `Loop` is causing the issue.